Building a Qt project with subprojects for Android

I have a Qt project in Qt Creator, which consists of 3 subprojects, and when I try to build it on Android Samsung A51 with the kit armeabi_v7a, I get an error:

No rule to make target 'C:\\..\\project-Android_Qt_6_7_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug\\src\\fp4App\\..\\fp4Lib\\libfp4Lib.a', needed by 'libfp4App_armeabi-v7a.so'.  Stop.

I tried to build an emulator for Android, I get the same error.

Problem seems to be in fp4Lib. Look in that directory and see what is wrong.

Alternatively, fp4App looks for libfp4Lib.a in wrong directory. That is actually most likely. See where it is written to for real.
